# Angular7 Validation Pattern to accept only integers and double values

Tags: regex, angular, angular7, angular-validation, angular-validator

I have wasted a lot of time on this already :(.

I want to accept only the integer or the double-positive numbers: 
ex: 
`40000`, `500.0000`, `400.1234`
I managed to do that for the integers:

```
// somewhere at the code 
export const NUMERIC_PATTREN = '^-?[0-9]\\d*(\\.\\d{1,2})?$';

// component code:
  amount: [{ value: entry.amount, disabled: false }, [Validators.required,Validators.pattern(NUMERIC_PATTREN )]],
```

However, the input is not accepting values from the format `500.0000` or `400.1234`. 
can anybody help me figure this out please.

*Update*
I want to limit the number of places after the point too.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Worked for me:

```
export const NUMERIC_PATTREN = '^-?[0-9]\\d*(\\.\\d{1,4})?$';
```

this will accept an integer number or a double number with maximum 4 places after the point.

If you want to increase or decrease the places after the point, you need to play with 4, ex:

```
export const NUMERIC_PATTREN = '^-?[0-9]\\d*(\\.\\d{1,3})?$'; //accepts only 3 places after the point
```

If you want unlimited places after the point you need to use:

```
export const NUMERIC_PATTREN = '^-?[0-9]\\d*(\\.\\d*)?$'; //accepts endless places
```

If you don't want the user to enter a zero to the left, then you need to start the domain from 1:

```
^-?[1-9]\\d*(\\.\\d{1,4})?$
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to accept integer or double with unlimited places after or before the point, this will help:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g75hxt

```
amount: [{ value: entry.amount, disabled: false }, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)]],
```

Comment: sorry that's not what I needed.

Comment: @FurqanS.Mahmoud , but you said that: 'I want to accept only the integer or the double-positive numbers'. It was your requirement.

Comment: sorry, I think I wasn't really clear, Yes I need that, plus I need to have only 4 places after the point in case the number is double. that's why I have to use the regular expression for that. 
min(0) validator is not enough.